# Custom JavaScript Object key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify the key for an AJAX POST within jQuery. If I replace the key with a variable, it seems to use the literal variable name instead of the value within.

```
$key = $(this).attr('id');

$.post( "php/register.php", { $key : $(this).val() }).done(function( data ) {
```

If the attribute was email I would expect to see:

```
email =>
string(15) "email@email.com"
```

Instead I get:

```
["$key"]=>
string(15) "email@email.com"
```

Does anybody know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible and how it can be done?

Comment: you meant object key, not json key.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use variables as a property like this. One alternative:

```
var data = {};
data[$key] = $(this).attr('id');
```

Then send the `data`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variables you want to handle in php in your ajax post.Replace $key with 'email'.